# Hide element when click on button and pageload

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, wordpress

I cannot get my head around this problem I am having, I hope that my writing is not to complicated to read.

I am making a product with 3 variables. A customer can pickup the products at our place, or we can deliver the products. Because of practical things, we choose to sell products there should be delivered as packages with 30, 60 or 90 products in.

Before a price can be shown, all 3 variables need to get selected. So here comes the problem. If a person wants to pickup the products at our place only 2 variables need to be selected: *Length in m and Pickup or Delivery*. But that will not give a price. Therefore I need to insert *"Pickup"* in **"Packages"** again to get a price.

But I would like to hide "pickup" in packages, so I do not confuse the visitor to much. The image describes what I am looking for:

[image]

A demo of the page [can be seen here](https://dev.onlinerelation.dk/produkt/stack/)

I was looking at the CSS. Is that what I have to use together with javascript, or how/if it is possible?

```
<ul class="variable-items-wrapper button-variable-wrapper" data-attribute_name="attribute_pa_packages">
    <li data-wvstooltip="pickup" class="variable-item button-variable-item button-variable-item-pickup" title="pickup" data-value="pickup">
        <span class="variable-item-span variable-item-span-button">pickup</span>
    </li>
</ul>

<ul class="variable-items-wrapper button-variable-wrapper" data-attribute_name="attribute_pa_packages">
    <li data-wvstooltip="pickup" class="variable-item button-variable-item button-variable-item-pickup selected" title="pickup" data-value="pickup">
        <span class="variable-item-span variable-item-span-button">pickup</span></li>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Best regards.

Comment: I would look more into why only choosing those 2 will not let you proceed. In a business logic scenario it makes more sense. Especially since if you choose pickup in the 'packages' area it actually locks out the delivery option, forcing you to reload if you change your mind. Without more code or examples it's hard to tell what exactly is going on, can you please give more snippets of your validation and form submission so we can see why it breaks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can listen for every time user clicks on one of the "Pickup or delivery" options, if the selected option is "pickup", select the "pickup" option in "Packages" with JQuery. This is the implementation of this algorithm.

```
jQuery("ul[data-attribute_name=attribute_pa_pickup-og-delivery] li").click(function(){
    var selectedDelivery = jQuery("ul[data-attribute_name=attribute_pa_pickup-og-delivery]").find("li.selected").attr("data-value");
    if (selectedDelivery == "pickup"){
        jQuery("ul[data-attribute_name=attribute_pa_packages] li[data-value=pickup] span").click();
        jQuery("ul[data-attribute_name=attribute_pa_packages] li[data-value=pickup]").hide(); // hide the "pickup" option in "Packages" if you like
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for the answer @Parham. So that I need to wrap in some php and add it to the functions.php in my child theme, right?

Comment: @Mv27 no these codes are Javascript/Jquery. 1) you should create a Js file with these codes. 2) edit your function.php in your child theme and enqueue this js file to your theme.